# Is it possible to disable the extremely annoying light bulb in Pycharm 2020.2?

Tags: pycharm

I'm referring to this little pest here:

The lightbulb, a successor of the infamous MSOffice clip:
[image: The lightbulb, a successor of the infamous MSOffice clip]

I went to editor.xml, but am not seeing the option mentioned in the other post about disabling the light bulb:

```
Option name="SHOW_INTENTION_BULB" value="true"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the light bulb with the following steps:

```
File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance
```

There you can find this option. Tick the check button and it should be not vissible anymore:

[image]

I found this solution in the [support portal](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206746429/comments/360000014339) of jetbrains.

Comment: Does it exist In windows?

Comment: Yes of course. I use Windows 10 and the current pycharm version.